# LaTeX mixing groups of images and tables

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents

Tthe below code is supposed to display five images, one table, another five images and another table. For some reason LaTeX displays first the images (all 10 of them) and then the two tables. The only way i can work around this is by spreading them in two pages, then they are displayed properly, but I want them to appear in the same page. Is there a reason why LaTeX is joining them by its own?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\noindent\rule{18.9cm}{0.1pt}
\newline
\hspace{10em}\uline{\textsc{Group1}\hfill}
\break \break \break
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}
\caption*{img1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img2}
\caption*{img2}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img3}
\caption*{img3}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img4}
\caption*{img4}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img5}
\caption*{img5}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]
\miniscule
\caption*{Group1}
\hspace*{-.5cm}
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}}
\toprule
\field1 & \field2 & field3 & field4 & \textbf{6M} &  \textbf{3M}&  \textbf{1W} &  \textbf{5} &  \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{ROE} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{1} \\
\midrule
Estee & 88.56 & -9.14 & 8.13 & -5.08 & .19 & 1.32 & 33,068 & 29.93 & 1.36 & 19.23 & 30.90 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\noindent\rule{18.9cm}{0.1pt}
\newline
\hspace{10em}\uline{\textsc{Group2}\hfill}
\break \break \break
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img6}
\caption*{img6}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img7}
\caption*{img7}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img8}
\caption*{img8}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img9}
\caption*{img9}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img10}
\caption*{img10}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]
\miniscule
\caption*{Group2}
\hspace*{-.5cm}
\scalebox{0.9}{
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}}
\toprule
\field1 & \field2 & field3 & field4 & \textbf{6M} &  \textbf{3M}&  \textbf{1W} &  \textbf{5} &  \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{ROE} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{1} \\
\midrule
test & 155.26 & -40.39 & -27.10 & -16.73 & -5.89 & 2.32 & 1,975 & 23.33 & -- & 19.90 & 18.98 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
test & 47.44 & -13.04 & -5.30 & -2.18 & .47 & 1.91 & 19,224 & 18.09 & 1.43 & 35.31 & 69.54 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
Constellation & 166.49 & -1.29 & 28.07 & 10.61 & 7.77 & 1.43 & 33,963 & 33.42 & 0.96 & 32.81 & 17.74 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example has lots of commands that are not defined `\miniscule` `\field` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified that the figures *must* float, they can not be positioned where they appear in the source (`[!tbp]`) but conversely you have specified that tables may be placed "here" but may not be placed on float pages or at the bottom of the page  (`[ht]`)

So in this case the tables are positioned using `h` but the figures float to the top of the page. so you get all 10 images first.

The default behaviour, without the optional arguments, produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\def\field{}
\def\miniscule{}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\rule{18.9cm}{0.1pt}
\newline
\hspace{10em}\uline{\textsc{Group1}\hfill}
\break \break \break
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img1}
\caption*{img1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img2}
\caption*{img2}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img3}
\caption*{img3}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img4}
\caption*{img4}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img5}
\caption*{img5}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\miniscule
\caption*{Group1}
\hspace*{-.5cm}
\scalebox{0.9}{%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}}
\toprule
\field1 & \field2 & field3 & field4 & \textbf{6M} &  \textbf{3M}&  \textbf{1W} &  \textbf{5} &  \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{ROE} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{1} \\
\midrule
Estee & 88.56 & -9.14 & 8.13 & -5.08 & .19 & 1.32 & 33,068 & 29.93 & 1.36 & 19.23 & 30.90 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\noindent\rule{18.9cm}{0.1pt}
\newline
\hspace{10em}\uline{\textsc{Group2}\hfill}
\break \break \break
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img6}
\caption*{img6}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img7}
\caption*{img7}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img8}
\caption*{img8}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img9}
\caption*{img9}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.18\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img10}
\caption*{img10}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\miniscule
\caption*{Group2}
\hspace*{-.5cm}
\scalebox{0.9}{%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}p{1.2cm}}
\toprule
\field1 & \field2 & field3 & field4 & \textbf{6M} &  \textbf{3M}&  \textbf{1W} &  \textbf{5} &  \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{ROE} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{1} \\
\midrule
test & 155.26 & -40.39 & -27.10 & -16.73 & -5.89 & 2.32 & 1,975 & 23.33 & -- & 19.90 & 18.98 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
test & 47.44 & -13.04 & -5.30 & -2.18 & .47 & 1.91 & 19,224 & 18.09 & 1.43 & 35.31 & 69.54 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
Constellation & 166.49 & -1.29 & 28.07 & 10.61 & 7.77 & 1.43 & 33,963 & 33.42 & 0.96 & 32.81 & 17.74 & N/A & N/A & N/A
\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, they appear properly grouped in my document now. Is it possible to bring every table to the images a bit closer, so they don't appear that separated?